# What is the form of particular solution for the following ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation
$$F_1''+2F_1'=A_0-1-A_0e^{-2X}+2A_0Xe^{-2X},\quad F_1(0)=0$$
I am not looking for the solution, I just want to know the form of the particular solution I should try.

Which one of these should I try, where $C,D,E$ are constants
$$F_1(X)=(CX+DX^2)e^{-2X}+EX,$$
$$F_1(X)=DX^2e^{-2X}+EX,$$
I am not sure whether $C=0$ or $C\neq0$.

The solution to the homogeneous equation is
$$F_1(X)=A_1e^{-2X}+B_1.$$

Comment: In my answer below I assumed $A_0$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve via method of undetermined coefficients you look at the homogeneous equation, which as you provided is $F_1 (x) = C_1 e^{-2x} + C_2$. Now by the right hand side of your given ODE, let's make a solution first without considering the homogeneous equation.

**Initial "Guess" Particular**: $A + (B + Cx)e^{-2x}$, since that's our right hand side with arbitrary constants $A, B,$ and $C.$ Now we will adjust based off of homogeneous equation.

**Adjusted "Guess" Particular**: $Ax + (Bx + Cx^2)e^{-2x}$, we adjusted this way because we had one copy of $C_1e^{-2x}$ as well as one constant $C_2$ which was repeated in our initial guess, so we had to adjust accordingly to preserve linear independence of our solution set to the ODE.

The take away is that you need to look for repetition with your initial guess based off the right hand side with your homogeneous solution in order to construct your particular solution so that it remains linearly independent.

So as you have it written you should try,
$$F_1 (X) = (CX + DX^2)e^{-2X} + EX.$$

Also, I call it a "Guess" because you may end up finding that these arbitrary constants are zero sometimes.

Comment: In this case, plugging $F_1(X)=(CX+DX^2)e^{-2X}+EX$ into the ODE gives $C=0$, that's why I asked the question. Can we determine whether $C=0$ or not beforehand?

Comment: @Hogg Generally you cannot with method of undetermined coefficients.